# Is it possible to set a time limit on an active ssh connection for a specific linux user?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am currently working on an idea for a fun CTF challenge. One of the major hurdles of this challenge however is allowing a user a specific amount of time on an ssh connection.

Essentially the user must ssh into a linux VM using the challenge user. They have 10 minutes to find 10 pieces of the flag that must be arranged in a certain order before the SSH session is terminated triggering an event that swaps the location of the flag pieces around. At this point the user must open a new SSH connection and continue searching.

The main issue here is limiting the amount of time the user has. Is this even possible with SSH? If so how do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would suggest looking into running a cron job when a specific user logs on to the VM. Then make the script end the user session after 10 minutes. EDIT: Even just running a login/startup script as the user could be enough I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, doing it THROUGH SSH would be prohibitively difficult. I think the easiest way would be to have a background program start running every time you have an ssh login to a specific account, which, after 10 minutes, kills all the ssh connections. Honestly it would be very easy.

You'd add something to ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc that says something like

```
sleep 600
killall --user {whateverhis/herusernameis}
end
```

or you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config`. It is ensured it will be executed after login:

```
Match User ctfuser
  ForceCommand "(sleep 600; killall -u ctfuser)& bash"
```

If you need only shell access, this is sufficient. If you need also SFTP or SCP, you need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: `ForceCommand timeout 600 bash` should be enough